# How can I retrieve MySQL data into a PHP array and then use that array to run another query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a MySQL database in which there is a table that serves as a master list of representative names ids and his/her respective manager, a table that serves as a list of managers, and four additional tables which serve as time intervals in which daily sales data is recorded (calls taken, time taken after each call, revenue, envelopes, pens and other). I am attempting to gather all the statistics for each representative under a single given manager, four times in a day. My thinking is that I should first gather the names and ids under a given manager, and then use that array(?) to run a query through the various tour intervals to gather the sales statistics. What is the best way to do this?

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
// Get last name of manager
$query = "SELECT * FROM managers WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['manager_name'] ."';";

$result = $mysqli -> query($query);

$row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$manager_first = $row[1];
$manager_last = $row[2];

// Get team members
$rep_query = "SELECT * FROM rep_master WHERE leader = '" . $manager_last . "';";

$rep_list = array();
$rep_result = $mysqli -> query($rep_query);

if ($rep_result) {
    while ($rep_row = $rep_result -> fetch_row()) {
        array_push($rep_list, $rep_row[1] . " " . $rep_row[2]);
    }
};

sort($rep_list);

print_r($rep_list);
// Stat query (using my ID as a testing point)
$stat_query = "SELECT id, total_calls, acw, revenue, envelopes, pens, other FROM tour_1 WHERE id='T441241';";

// Get row data
$stat_row = $stat_result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
echo '<br /><br />';
print_r($stat_row);

?>
```

Comment: This sounds possible to do in a single query by using two JOINS and doing a UNION on the data in the 4 tables. Is that preferred or is there any condition that requires the queries to be done separately?

Answer (score 0):

Use IN and implode:

```
print_r($rep_list);
// Stat query (using my ID as a testing point)
$stat_query = "SELECT id, total_calls, acw, revenue, envelopes, pens, other 
               FROM tour_1 WHERE id IN(".implode(",",$rep_list).")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tour tables all have the same structure, you could use UNIONs on the four shift tables and two LEFT JOINs to do this in a single query. I've added a column to show which tour the info came from. Here, it's not clear how you want to group and filter the statistics, so you may get multiple rows with the same leader and rep. You can add GROUP BY modifiers within the *combinedtours* nested query and WHERE filters or ORDER BY modifiers at the appropriate locations to optimise the query and group, filter and order the records accordingly.

```
SELECT `managers`.*, CONCAT(`rep_master`.`first_name`, ' ', `rep_master`.`last_name`), combinedtours.* FROM `managers` 

RIGHT JOIN 
`rep_master` ON `rep_master`.`leader` = `managers`.`last_name`

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id, 1 as tour, total_calls, acw, revenue, envelopes, pens, other FROM tour_1
UNION
SELECT id, 2 as tour, total_calls, acw, revenue, envelopes, pens, other FROM tour_2
UNION
SELECT id, 3 as tour, total_calls, acw, revenue, envelopes, pens, other FROM tour_3
UNION
SELECT id, 4 as tour, total_calls, acw, revenue, envelopes, pens, other FROM tour_4
) combinedtours
ON combinedtours.`id` = `rep_master`.`rep_id`
```

Comment: I like this. Question for you: in which table would the combinedtours column live?

Comment: combinedtours is not a column but an alias to represent the result of a nested query. It is used as an intermediary to extract the statistics that you need

Comment: As I'm not exactly fluent yet in MySQL, am I simply able to use the script above in a console query?

Comment: If the table and field names used correspond to yours then yes. I assumed that your table names are: managers, tour_1, tour_2, tour_3 and tour_4. The field names were all taken from your post except for `managers`.`last_name`, `rep_master`.`first_name`, `rep_master`.`last_name` and `rep_master`.`rep_id`, which you should be able to change to the correct field names if you know the names of the columns in your tables.

Comment: Perfect. However, when I run a `print_r` command in PHP it returns the manager's ID, manager's first name, manager's last name, manager's password, and the first and last name of the first representative in that manager's list along with his/her stats.

Comment: I should also mention the query only returns one representative. Do I have to loop through each representative and run the query for each one?

Comment: The query you listed was select * from manager so it selected all fields from the manager, which seems to include he manager's password. Obviously, You would need to modify the query to select only the relevant fields from the manager table. As for returning a single representative, I've modified he query by changing the first join to a RIGHT JOIN.